# SetBkColor and SetTextColor Don't set the background and text color for DrawText

Tags: windows, winapi, desktop, gdi, realbasic

Using the following code to write a string to the DesktopWindow's device context works, but the background color and text color remain the same (white on blue):

```
Private Sub writeToScreen(txt As String)
Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Integer
Declare Function DrawTextW Lib "user32" (hdc As Integer, lpStr As WString, nCount As Integer, _
     ByRef lpRect As RECT, wFormat As Integer) As Integer
Declare Function CreateDCA Lib "gdi32" (lpDriverName As CString, lpDeviceName As Integer, _
     lpOutput As Integer, lpInitData As Integer) As Integer
Declare Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32" (hdc As Integer) As Integer
Declare Function GetTextColor Lib "gdi32" (hdc As Integer) As Color
Declare Function SetTextColor Lib "gdi32" (hdc As Integer,  crColor As Color) As Color
Declare Function GetBkColor Lib "gdi32" (hdc As Integer) As Color
Declare Function SetBkColor  Lib "gdi32" (hdc As Integer,  crColor As Color) As Color

Const DT_MULTILINE = &H00000001
Const DT_NOCLIP = &H100
Const INVALID_COLOR = &hFFFFFFFF

Dim tFormat As Integer = DT_MULTILINE Or DT_NOCLIP
Dim hdc As Integer = CreateDCA("DISPLAY", 0, 0, 0)
Dim tRect As RECT   //The RECT structure is defined elsewhere
Dim textCol, backColor As Color

tR.Left = 200
tR.Top = 250
tR.Right = 600
tR.Bottom = 350
textCol = SetTextColor(hdc, &cFF8040)
backColor = SetBkColor(hdc, &c000000)

If DrawTextW(hdc, txt, Len(txt), tR, tFormat) = 0 Then
  System.DebugLog("Text Draw Error")
End If

Call SetTextColor(hdc, textCol)
Call SetBkColor(hdc, backColor)
Call DeleteDC(hdc)  
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong? The text gets written just fine, but the colors are ugly.

Comment: **The main thing you're doing wrong is drawing directly to the desktop.** You are **never** supposed to do that. You do not own the desktop window. Windows owns the desktop window. And just as you learned as a toddler, you should not steal and deface things which you do not own. Now, go redesign your application.

Comment: Use Graphics.FromHdc() and TextRenderer.DrawText() instead.

Comment: @Cody Gray No argument there, but that's not what I asked.

Comment: Hmm, I see the original comment started with something about nosebleeds up in this level, presumably of abstraction. But this isn't merely abstract preaching. There are very real reasons why **you should not do this**. I also realize that it's not what you asked. Technically speaking, that's why I posted it as a comment, rather than an answer. But far more importantly, it is very real advice that you should *strongly* consider before moving forward with this project. Even if you get this to "work", you're going to run into far bigger problems down the road. Always seems nice to know that.

Comment: I wish people had stopped me and told me "you're doing it all wrong" plenty of times in the past. Preferably sooner rather than later. It's amazing on Stack Overflow to see so many users who resent that advice. If you're not looking for well-reasoned advice from seasoned developers, then maybe you'd be more interested in a site like http://www.rentacoder.com instead?

Comment: @Cody Gray I apologize for the original comment. I hadn't intended it to be posted which is why it was edited seconds after it went up. I am fully aware of why this is a bad idea. I nevertheless would like to know why the DC's color settings are not being changed. Preaching about practices helps me not at all here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SetBkMode() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162965%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) first to set the DC to not draw a background.

SetTextColor() is only used for TextOut(), not DrawText(), IIRC - MSDN is ambiguous on it. Try seleting a different HBRUSH into the DC, that may do what you want.